# How risky is a direct cast between compatible enums?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have the following direct cast between two enums:

```
_viewModel.ServiceStatus = (HostServiceStatus)(HostController.Status);
```

The enums are:

```
public enum ServiceControllerStatus
{
    Stopped = 1,
    StartPending = 2,
    StopPending = 3,
    Running = 4,
    ContinuePending = 5,
    PausePending = 6,
    Paused = 7,
}
public enum HostServiceStatus
{
    // NB Do not ever change 1 to 6. These map directly to ServiceControllerStatus.
    NotInstalled = 0,
    Stopped = 1,
    StartPending = 2,
    StopPending = 3,
    Running = 4,
    ContinuePending = 5,
    PausePending = 6,
    Paused = 7,
    Disabled = 8
}
```

Where `ServiceControllerStatus` is part of the CLR, and defined in `System.ServiceProcess`. I doubt this will change anytime soon.

I'm asking because I just found an unrelated bug, but in the process of tracking it down, I found `_viewModel.ServiceStatus` still always had value of zero. Then I replaced the direct cast with the following, only to find the bug still existed:

```
var cs = HostController.Status;
HostServiceStatus hs;
Enum.TryParse(cs.ToString(), out hs);
_viewModel.ServiceStatus = hs;
```

The the direct cast is actually working fine, but this raised, what is to me, the quite important question about the risk of the direct cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, enums are just ints (unless you specify otherwise). So technically, casting an enum value into another type which does not have a field for that value isn't "dangerous":

```
ServiceControllerStatus status = (ServiceControllerStatus)HostServiceStatus.Disabled;
```

The value of `status` would then simply be `8`.

The danger of course is already in the comment of your enum declaration: changing an enum value of one enumeration causes your application to still compile, but behave quite differently or even crash.

You could refer to the source enum to make the relationship between these enums more visible:

```
public enum HostServiceStatus
{
    NotInstalled = 0,
    Stopped = ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped,
    StartPending = ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending,
    ...
```

Note that these values are applied at compile time; if `ServiceControllerStatus` is declared in another assembly than `HostServiceStatus`, and the *values* of `ServiceControllerStatus` are changed, these changes will not be reflected in `HostServiceStatus` until you recompile it.

Comment: Thank you. I understand all about enums being ints, but wasn't sure how the runtime would handle int values that don't exist etc. I will apply your advice to use the source enum. Like I said, I doubt `ServiceControllerStatus` will change too soon, as it's CLR, but it is quite easy to recompile the `HostServiceStatus` assembly if it ever does.